# Get GUID from `WinAppDeployCmd devices` command

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-phone, uwp, windows-10

Running `WinAppDeployCmd devices` command in **Windows PowerShell** returns information(like GUID, IP Address etc.) about all devices/phone connected to windows 10 machine.

How do I Filter results to only give me **GUID** of all connected devices.

I have tried `WinAppDeployCmd devices 1  | select GUID` command but it doesn't work. Check below image.

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve **GUID** of devices from this command.

Note: `WinAppDeployCmd devices` command returns proper information about the connected device.

Comment: The command returns what appears to be a string array not an object. Try WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices | ConvertFrom-String | Select P3

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan: thanks a lot.

I was able to retrieve guid using below command:

`$guid = WinAppDeployCmd.exe devices 1| ConvertFrom-String | Select P2`

`$guid.P2[5]`